# How do you limit a React app to only one path on a website?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I have a website with static HTML files located in `/public`, but one page (with more to come) will be React.

Right now my React router is consuming everything and making the static HTML files inaccessible.

How can I tell the router to get out of the way when dealing with a file in `/public`?

Comment: This would be handled by what ever server you are using. Something must be serving the HTML that includes your React application when these URLs are directly requested. React Router only comes into effect on the client side.

Comment: How is a typical node server configured for this? For example run `npm run build && serve -s build` to get a server up and running.

Comment: serve using a default setup just serves files from the directory that is run in and should not be blocking you from your public folder. Do you have a serve.json file? Also are you using a template like CRA or Nextjs etc?

Comment: I'm just using the default `serve -s` command, and also running on Netlify which I don't have control over and I have no idea how it is configured. All the static stuff in `/public` is being intercepted by React and trying to be loaded.